# Allow user to open phone gallary, select an image and then post to Facebook Wall

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

Still i am using below code, in which i have given a specific image to post on wall everytime, but now i want to allow user to open phone gallery and select an image and then post to facebook wall

Please write some code how to open gallery then select an image to post and also show how can i show selected image in my working code, like still i am using this line:

```
                params.putString("picture", 
                                        FacebookUtility.HACK_ICON_URL);
```

Complete Code for ItemClick:

```
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
        int position, long id) {

    try {
        final long friendId;
        friendId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getLong("uid");
        String name = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("name");
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.post_on_wall_title)
                .setMessage(
                        String.format(getString(R.string.post_on_wall),
                                name))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {


                                Bundle params = new Bundle();

                                params.putString("to",
                                        String.valueOf(friendId));
                                params.putString("caption",
                                        getString(R.string.app_name));
                                params.putString("description",
                                        getString(R.string.app_desc));
                                params.putString("link", 
                                        "http://www.XXX.com");
                                params.putString("picture", 
                                        FacebookUtility.HACK_ICON_URL);                         
                                params.putString("name",
                                        getString(R.string.app_action));
                                FacebookUtility.facebook
                                        .dialog(FriendsList.this,
                                                "feed",
                                                params,
                                                (DialogListener) new PostDialogListener());
                            }

                        }).setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null).show();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        showToast("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Bitmap bmpScale;
public static byte[] data;      

       builder.setNegativeButton("Gallery",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    openGallery(SELECT_FILE1);

                }
            });


                public void openGallery(int SELECT_FILE1) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select file to upload "),
            SELECT_FILE1);

    // new UploadMediaAsyncTask().execute();
}



    // ..................
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    Uri selectedImageUri = null;
    String filePath = null;
    switch (requestCode) {
    case SELECT_FILE1:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE1) {
                selectedPath1 = getPath(selectedImage);
                // mimagepath.setText(selectedPath1);
                Toast.makeText(Camera.this, "" + selectedPath1 + "", 500)
                        .show();

                if (selectedPath1 != null) {

                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
                    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                    // image path `String` where your image is located
                    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedPath1, options);

                    int bitmapWidth = 400;
                    int bitmapHeight = 250;
                    final int height = options.outHeight;
                    final int width = options.outWidth;
                    int inSampleSize = 1;
                    if (height > bitmapHeight || width > bitmapWidth) {
                        if (width > height) {
                            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height
                                    / (float) bitmapHeight);
                        } else {
                            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width
                                    / (float) bitmapWidth);
                        }
                    }

                    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

                     bmpScale = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
                            selectedPath1, options);

                    imgggg.setImageBitmap(bmpScale);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    // CompressFormat set up to JPG, you can change to PNG
                    // or
                    // whatever you
                    // want;

                    bmpScale.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                    bmpScale.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                    // **********************
                    //  
                //globaly..................................
                    data = bos.toByteArray();



                }

                // Log.d("setpath ", "setpath " + selectedPath1);
                // Log.d("setpath ", "setpath " + selectedPath1);
                // System.out.println("selectedPath1 : " + selectedPath1);
                // mimagepath.setText(selectedPath1);

            }
        }

        break;


}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```